# less secure app in gmail setting programmatically in Java

Tags: java, android, jakarta-mail, gmail-imap

I am beginner in android development.I develop an android app that reads emails from gmail server, but gmail not allow to get access form less secure app. for that i manually "Turn On"the settings to get gmail emails then access my account emails and its works fine.
link to "Turn On and OFF" access settings is:

https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en

Can its possible that i turn On and OFF my gmail account  settings programmatically.
Please give me some Guidance..

Comment: The alternative is to actually implement OAuth, which is the correct way to bypass that setting.  Google provides libraries for this.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [Gmail API Overview](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/), what you want to do is not mentioned in the docs so it may not be supported yet. Even the [Users.settings](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/#Users.settings) does not mention this. So for the time being , you'll have to do this manually as there's no programmatic way of doing this.